# Consent message not showing up

Tags: flutter, firebase-admob, gdprconsentform, admob-cookieconsent

I am using firebase_admob with admob_consent package. I am not able to see consent message.
I am getting following lines in terminal.

`I/UserMessagingPlatform(10516): Use new ConsentDebugSettings.Builder().addTestDeviceHashedId("E044C97978FC060327A4C4F01EE86A88") to set this as a debug device. D/UserMessagingPlatform(10516): Stored info not exists: IDFA_freqCapNumViews D/UserMessagingPlatform(10516): Stored info not exists: IABTCF_TCString D/UserMessagingPlatform(10516): Stored info not exists: IABTCF_AddtlConsent`

Does consent message pop up only in EU countries?
coz I am from India.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes consent only shows up in EU. For testing you can use following code:

```
ConsentDebugSettings debugSettings = new ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(this)
            .setDebugGeography(ConsentDebugSettings
                    .DebugGeography
                    .DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA)
            .addTestDeviceHashedId("E044C97978FC060327A4C4F01EE86A88")
            .build();

// Google CMP implementation:
ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters
        .Builder()
        .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
        .setConsentDebugSettings(debugSettings)
        .build();
```

Comment: What to do with params?